# Reuse of the same variable wit using echo and cut

Tags: bash, variables

I'm try to make a script for checking some ethx.

If the eth is up and connected my script is working

When its not working I have a problem.

```
RESD=$(ssh -q vmx@$1 cat /sys/class/net/$3/dormant)
```

I get in RESD the following result:

```
cat: /sys/class/net/eth3/dormant: Invalid argument
```

I want to put in RESD now the first letter.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: The first letter of what exactly?

Comment: Is this what you want to do: `RESD=${RESD:0:1}`? This is pure bash equivalent of `RESD=$(echo $RESD | cut -c1)`.

Comment: thanks pgl I used the second option and the script works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment above, this what you want to do: `RESD=${RESD:0:1}`? This is pure bash equivalent of `RESD=$(echo $RESD | cut -c1)`.